# Sprite appears for a frame then disappears {LibGDX}

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

```
public void chooseLane() {
    lane = MathUtils.random(1, 3);
    System.out.println(lane);
    spawnCar();
}

public void spawnCar() {
    if(lane == 1){
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(carsb, carP1X, carP1Y);
        batch.end();
    }
    if(lane == 2){
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(carsb, carP2X, carP2Y);
        batch.end();
    }
    if(lane == 3){
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(carsb, carP3X, carP3Y);
        batch.end();
    }
```

Sprite appears for pretty much one frame then disappears. I'm guessing it has something to do with this all not being in the `render()` method, but I'm not sure how to shift this into that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you call `chooseLane()` from your `create()`, `show()` or `resume()` method. That means that you will once spawn a car, choose a lane for that new car and then draw it once on the screen.

After that LibGDX will move to the endless loop and will keep call your `render()` method continuously. Probably you followed some tutorial and got something like `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` in your render method. This will then clear your screen and remove your drawn car. After that it won't be drawn again.

You should probably change your code which looks like the following:

```
public void chooseLane() {
    lane = MathUtils.random(1, 3);
    System.out.println(lane);
}

public void drawCar() {
    batch.begin();
    if(lane == 1){
        batch.draw(carsb, carP1X, carP1Y);
    }
    if(lane == 2){
        batch.draw(carsb, carP2X, carP2Y);
    }
    if(lane == 3){
        batch.draw(carsb, carP3X, carP3Y);
    }
    batch.end();
}

public void create()/show()/resume() { // choose whatever fits your case here
    chooseLane();
}

public void render(float deltaTime) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawCar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got the Sprite to stay on screen but now my Timer is broken >.> I've set a `long lastSpawn;` + an `if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastSpawn > 1000000000){
   chooseLane();
  }` with a `lastSpawn = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
` in the spawnCar method. The timer was running perfectly before I changed things up, can't seem to work out whats causing it to stop counting past one now =P

Comment: The render method as a parameter called delta which is the time passed since the last frame was renderered. I assume you want to update the game every second? create a variable called passedDelta and keep adding the delta value to it until passedDelta is > 1, update the game, and reset passedDelta.